# Screen tool on Galileo

Tags: linux, yocto, intel-galileo

I have compiled and installed screen tool on Galileo running on Yocto.
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

When I run the tool everything is OK, I can create many sessions. However when I close the terminal all my sessions are closed (when I do "screen -ls" from other terminal there are no sockets). This is not happening in any other Linux distribution.

Regards,
Yevgeniy

Answer (score 0):

Are you running screen from inside a ssh connection?  There was a bug in earlier releases of the devkit where on disconnect systemd killed all processes started by the daemon, which isn't what you want.  This has been fixed so upgrading your image should be sufficient.

If you can't get the upgrade, the fix is to add "KillMode=process" to the end of /lib/systemd/system/ssh@.service.